# Is it safe to change "Subversion Workspace Version" option on a Jenkins installation?

Tags: svn, jenkins

We have a large Jenkins installation that currently is building over 70 jobs.
Currently we are experiencing some problems, so we'd like to upgrade current Subversion Workspace Version (1.4) to 1.6, and we notice there is an option to do it in the Manage Jenkins section.
My question is, if it's safe to do that because jenkins will upgrade workspaces automatically, or if all the jobs will begin to fail and a manual update of workspace version should be done after changing that property. 
Thanks!

Comment: Safest bet is to wipe all the workspaces. New format will be used next time each one is run.

Comment: I guess I could try changing that property and testing with one job. If it fails, then I will wipe out workspace, if that works, next thing to do is wipe out all workspaces. Thanks!